# How to insert a number in the place I need in a string, in the C programming language

Tags: c, algorithm, file

I'm just starting to write in the C language, I ran into a small problem related more to algorithms than to the features of the language.

In my program, the task is to insert the file size after the _ symbol, if there is one in the file name.

I don't quite understand how this can be implemented, maybe someone will tell you and there is a ready-made algorithm that copes with this, insert a number into a string (array of characters)

Here is an example of my code, with explanations of where and what is being done:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    DIR * p;
    p = opendir("."); // Open catalog
    if(p!=NULL){ // check on error
        struct dirent * dir;

        while((errno=0, dir=readdir(p))){  // Reading catalog
            struct stat infoAboutFile;
            int res = stat(dir->d_name, &infoAboutFile);
            if(res==0){ // check on error
                if(S_ISREG(infoAboutFile.st_mode)){ // Check on regular files
                    char str[256];
                    strcpy(str,dir->d_name);
                    int size = infoAboutFile.st_size; //Size file                   
                    
                    printf("\n");
                }
            }else{
                perror("Errors in Stat");
            }
        }
        if(errno!=0){ // check on error
            perror("Errors in Readdir");
        }
        

        int res = closedir(p);
        if(res==-1){ // check on errorr
            perror("Errors in Closedir");
        }
    }else{
        perror("Errors in Opendir");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Rather than `char str[256];`, you probably want to use `char str[PATH_MAX]` (PATH_MAX is defined in <limits.h>)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `sprintf`:

```
sprintf( str, "%s_%d", dir->d_name, size );
```

You will need to make sure `str` is wide enough for the final string.

**EDIT**

William Pursell points out in the comments that there's also `snprintf`, where you specify the maximum number of characters to write to the target buffer such that you avoid an accidental buffer overflow:

```
snprintf( str, sizeof str, "%s_%d", dir->d_name, size );
```

Personally, I prefer making sure the target buffer is large enough for the final string, rather than risk truncating the string.  The first thing we need to do is compute how large the buffer will need to be:

```
size_t str_len = strlen( dir->d_name ) // length of d_name
                 + 10                  // number of decimal digits in a 32-bit int
                 + 1;                  // for the '_' character
```

If your compiler supports variable-length arrays, then we just declare an array with size `str_len`:

```
char str[ str_len + 1 ];  // +1 for the string terminator
```

Otherwise, we need to allocate that buffer dynamically:

```
char *str = malloc( str_len + 1 ); // +1 for the string terminator
```

Then you can use regular `sprintf`:

```
sprintf( str, "%s_%d", dir->d_name, size );
```

If you use `malloc`, then you will have to remember to deallocate `str` with `free` when you're done with it.

Comment: Perhaps it would be appropriate to demonstrate `snprintf`

Comment: Thank you very much, for your answer, you very help me.
The question is closed!